# Printing HTML on specific printer with Golang

Tags: html, linux, windows, go, printing

I am developing a desktop app and I want to print HTML on a physical printer of my choosing on Windows and Linux.

It shouldn't ask the user to choose a printer as I want it to be automated without user input.

Is it possible with pure go and without executing external binaries?
If not which binaries do I need for windows and which for linux?

I found a way that works by using chrome command line flags. Namely `--kiosk-printing` and `--headless` and `--user-data-dir` so a new instance is spawned.
The Javascript necessary is:

```
window.print();
setTimeout(function() {
    var ww = window.open(window.location, '_self');
    ww.close();
}, 1250);
```

The timeout is necessary because chrome's print() doesn't block so we need to wait until it was actually printed.
This way I can print silently without asking the user and this works with Windows and Linux.
However I can't find a way to choose the printer that's used.

Comment: If the user isn't able to choose a printer, they will NEVER come back to your site. They know that they will need to choose a printer and they will find it extremely creepy. Why don't you want them to choose a printer??

Comment: I am not developing a website. I am developing a desktop app. I want to be able to choose the printer, because then I can hardcode one printer for each kind of print. (Theres different paper in each one)

Comment: I know nothing about printing, so i probably wont be able to answer any your question without further research. Though, a simple search on github revealed a number of repositories that appear to implement that functionality. https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=printing&type=Repositories You might also want to check for https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector (it does provide a local mode)

Comment: I looked through the list and the only one that does actual printing [doesn't do pdfs](https://github.com/alexbrainman/printer/issues/6). Even if it printed pdfs I'd still need a linux version (it only does windows) and a way to convert html to pdf on both OS's. I am not quite sure how the second link would help me print html. (Could you perhaps link a source where this library is used in that way?)